# Filter DOM nodes based on an array with multiple Ids using data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, underscore.js

Given the following markup

```
<div class="group-one">
  <span data-id="1">
  <span data-id="2">
  <span data-id="3">
</div>

<div class="group-two">
  <span data-id="1">
  <span data-id="2">
  <span data-id="3">
</div>
```

I want to filter the nodes by using an array of `data-id`

So if I have `ids=[1,2]` I want as a result the two nodes corresponding to those in the array, inside one of the groups.

```
ids=[1,2]
nodes = $(".group-one").children();
#nice way of filtering the nodes using ids array. With Jquery.filter or Underscore
```

I know I can iterate trough all the child nodes and compare each of the nodes `data-id` againts the ids array. But I want to know if this can be achieved by using only selectors o some other on liner kind of solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like a filter you looking for?

....children().filter( function(entry) { return ids.indexOf(entry.attributes["data-id"]) !== -1; })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with only jQuery selectors:

```
var filteredNodes = nodes.filter(function() {
    // Attributes are strings, so you have to convert int.
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'));
    return $.inArray(i, ids) >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter based on the data attributes ?

```
var ids=[1,2];

$('div span').filter(function() {
    return ids.indexOf( $(this).data('id') ) !=  -1;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/00kgkxp2/)